# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'unicode' in django models

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django model that perform background computation in the admin section and displays the content to the templates.

The models I created is having these error code.

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'unicode'
```

Here is my models.py

```
class Inv(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    sold = models.IntegerField( default=0)
    item_remaining = models.IntegerField(default=0, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

    def item_remaining(self):
        return self.quantity - self.sold
```

I believe the function the contains the computation has a fault which I can't fix

The Traceback gotten is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 174, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 172, in get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 160, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 137, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 95, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 206, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 197, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 992, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 173, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 197, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 992, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 173, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 197, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 992, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 69, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 992, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 69, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 992, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 959, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 223, in render
    _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py", line 326, in result_list
    'results': list(results(cl))}
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py", line 302, in results
    yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py", line 293, in __init__
    super(ResultList, self).__init__(*items)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py", line 202, in items_for_result
    f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 290, in lookup_field
    value = attr()
  File "C:\Users\Uchechukwu\Desktop\DoreenProject\doreenProject\doreenselly\models.py", line 49, in item_remaining
    return self.quantity - self.sold
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'unicode'
[22/Mar/2016 11:36:49] "GET /admin/doreenselly/addinventory/ HTTP/1.1" 500 260601
```

Comment: You should show the full traceback. Apart from anything else, it shows exactly what code is causing the error, and what you were doing at the time.

Answer (score 1):

You've given your method the same name as a field, judging by the calculation, you can just remove the field. Dont forget to `makemigrations`.

Alternatively, rename the method

Comment: commented out the field item_remaining in the Inv class but still didnt work

Comment: @uche - Did you `makemigrations/migrate`? What does "didn't work" entail? same error? you should update your question with the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the item_remaining function and write save function in that place

```
def save(self):
    self.item_remaining = self.quantity - self.sold
```

This save function will be called whenever an object is saved. So the item_remaining field will be updated whenever object is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can delete the field and make the item_remaining a property.
Now, you can use item_remaining as `"instance.item_remaining"`.

```
class Inv(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    sold = models.IntegerField( default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

    @property 
    def item_remaining(self):
        return self.quantity - self.sold
```